# How can I alter a player's helmet data? (Such as attributes)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Since you can't modify player nbt data with /data modify, I had to think of a workaround.

I thought to use /data modify to copy a player's helmet into a chest, modify the item there, and replace it back on the player.

So, while wearing a helmet, I tried:

```
/data modify block 31 241 16 Items[] set from entity @p Inventory
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't copy over the players armor items, offhand, or 3rd inventory row. It only copies their hotbar and first 2 inventory rows.

Then, I tried:

```
/data modify block 31 241 16 Items set from entity @p Inventory[{Slot:103b}]
```

This didn't work. (By the way, slot 103 is the player's head slot) And to be sure:

```
/data modify block 31 241 16 Items[{Slot:0b}] set from entity @p Inventory[{Slot:103b}]
```

But no items appeared in the chest, even though I was wearing a helmet.
However, this command works fine with item in my first hotbar slot:

```
/data modify block 31 241 16 Items[] set from entity @p Inventory[{Slot:0b}]
```

So I assume that /data modify just can't copy anything from a player's armor slots.

If that's the case, is there any way to modify a player's armor data?

Comment: This entire question is about modifying a block's data and then suddenly you ask how to edit player data? What?

Comment: @FabianRöling This person wants to modify the data of the helmet of some player, noticed that you can't easily change player NBT data and decided to copy the helmet into a chest... kinda... then modifying it in there. I'm not sure how you would make someone wear that particular helmet then, but I don't think that this question is unclear.

Comment: So the entire question comes down to "how to edit an item in a player inventory"?

Comment: @FabianRöling Yes. As far as I know though, that is impossible in vanilla minecraft currently.

Comment: Correct. There was a way to change a specific subset of player data using a bug, but that is fixed in the latest snapshot. The best you can do is clearing an item and re-giving it or using `/replaceitem`.

Comment: This might be a bug. You should post this on [Minecraft Jira Bug Tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa) just in case!

Comment: While this question is older, [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376895/is-it-possible-to-change-part-of-the-nbt-of-a-held-item) has the best answer. Therefore, I'm voting to close this one as a duplicate.